# Exit case in switch in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, exit

I am trying this code with exit case, the exit case doesn't work it still asks me for the two numbers and then it exits. I have provided the output. What is the alternative to the switch case that I can use for menu driven programs?

Sample input/output:

```
::::::Menu:::::

1. Addition:
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Mod
6. Exit

Enter your choice:6

Enter the values of a and b:3 4
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a,b,c;
    int no;
    do{

    printf("\n::::::Menu:::::\n");
    printf(" 1. Addition:\n 2. Subtraction \n 3. Multiplication \n 4. Division \n 5. Mod \n 6. Exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    printf("\nEnter the values of a and b:");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    switch(no){
        case 1:
                c = a + b;
                printf("\nAddition is:%d",c);
        break;

        case 2:
                c = a - b;
                printf("\nSubtraction is:%d",c);
        break;

        case 3:
                c = a * b;
                printf("\nMultiplication is:%d",c);
        break;

        case 4:
                c = a / b;
                printf("\nDivision is:%f",c);
        break;

        case 5:
                c = a % b;
                printf("\nMod is:%d",c);
        break;

        case 6:
            exit(1);
        default:
                printf("\nInvalid choice\n");
        break;  
        }

    }while(no!=6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check `no` after the `scanf`. If it is a 6, exit.

Comment: Of course it asks. Because you told it to ask regardless of previous input.

Comment: You are not checkingg if the input is 6 before asking the numbers...

Comment: 5 (!) answers for this question? Seriously?

Comment: Note that the `exit()` function exits the program; it never returns and there is no program running after it is done.  You don't use it as a way to get out of loops unless you really do want the program to halt.  If you want to break out of the `do { … } while (…);` loop (or any other loop) from within the `switch`, then you have to work a bit harder because a `break` exits the switch and not the loop.  A `goto` and a label, deprecated though they generally are, is one way to do it.  Often, you can place the switch in a function, and call the function from the loop.  Then you use `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program asks for two numbers because you are checking for the exit code after the second `scanf` statement. If you wish the program to exit when 6 is entered, then you have to add an if statement in between the first and second `scanf`. You should additionally removed the exit case from your switch statement. Below is an example:

```
printf("\nEnter your choice:");
scanf("%d",&no);
if (no == 6)
    exit(0);
printf("\nEnter the values of a and b:");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the user's menu option, then asking for the next two numbers **before** you get to the `switch` statement, so of course it will always ask for those two numbers.

You need to either check specifically for 6 right after reading the menu input, or you need to move the second prompts to only where they're needed, i.e. inside each case.

Answer (score 0):

The statements in `C` are meant to be executed sequentially unless you disrupt the normal flow of action using jumps. In your case

```
printf("\nEnter your choice:");
scanf("%d",&no);
printf("\nEnter the values of a and b:");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
// Only now does the switch start.
```

You ask for the choice first and then for the two numbers. That is why you always end up in entering the two values. One way is to take the exit out of the `switch-case` which perhaps is the simplest solution I guess. Something like

```
printf("\nEnter your choice:");
scanf("%d",&no);
if ( 6 == no )
      exit(1);
```

> What is the alternative to the switch case that I can use for menu
>   driven programs

Well, `switch-case` is exactly made for that. Why think of an alternative?

Comment: Also, can you help me with the character input? If I enter a character as an input then it goes into an infinite loop. Please share the code.

Comment: @PratikSondkar Character as input? I don't see a  place where you enter characters here.

Comment: @PratikSondkar Apart from the questions raised here, your pgm logic is seriously flawed. For instance the `do-while` loop is an overkill. You could replace that with `while(1){//do stuff here}`

Answer (score 0):

It keeps asking for the two numbers because the switch statement is positioned right AFTER you ask for the user input. I restructured your code, this should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
int a,b,c;
int no;

while(1){

printf("\n::::::Menu:::::\n");
printf(" 1. Addition:\n 2. Subtraction \n 3. Multiplication \n 4. Division \n 5. Mod \n 6. Exit");
printf("\nEnter your choice:");
scanf("%d",&no);
if (no == 6)
  break;

printf("\nEnter the values of a and b:");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

switch(no){
    case 1:
            c = a + b;
            printf("\nAddition is:%d",c);
    break;

    case 2:
            c = a - b;
            printf("\nSubtraction is:%d",c);
    break;

    case 3:
            c = a * b;
            printf("\nMultiplication is:%d",c);
    break;

    case 4:
            c = a / b;
            printf("\nDivision is:%f",c);
    break;

    case 5:
            c = a % b;
            printf("\nMod is:%d",c);
    break;

    default:
            printf("\nInvalid choice\n");
    break;  
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Note how I changed the do-while to a while-true and explicitly check for no == 6 PRIOR to asking for user input.

Comment: Also, can you help me with the character input? If I enter a character as an input then it goes into an infinite loop. Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("l.print l   c.print c      q. exit  \n");
        printf("enter choice ");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'l':
                    printf("You have typed l \n");
                    break;
            case 'c':
                    printf("yoh have typed c  \n");
                    break;
            case 'q':
                    exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```